# protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter doesn't show results for multicapabilities test

Tags: html, protractor, jasmine2.0, jasmine-reporters

That Html Reporter works fine when one browser is used but multiple browsers using protractor's multicapabilities property results are not displayed.

Here is how my config looks in onPrepare method:

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
    savePath: './reports/'
}));
```

I noticed the screenshots are available for other browsers runs in the reports/screenshot dir. Also, it prints the results of all browsers fine on command line. But it doesn't show anything in the html report other than results of one browser.

Is there a jasmine option I need to define? I tried the 'protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter' and it works fine for multiple browser results.

[image: sample report view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only specify one path, each browser session is probably overwriting the results of a previous session. To create a unique id for each report, in your config you can do something like:

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

onPrepare: function() {
    return browser.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
        var sessionId = caps.caps_['webdriver.remote.sessionid'];
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: './reports/' + sessionId
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks for that. Script works fine with minor adjustment of calling function(caps).

Comment: do you know if there is a way to consolidate all the results? like we had in jasmine1 html reporter? I tried setting consolidateAll flag but I don't see any difference

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin, but I would doubt it. When you're using multiCapabilities, each browser instance is started independently with its onPrepare adding the reporter for that session only. Essentially each reporter doesn't know about any other reporter, so they can't consolidate reports. I think you would have to make a shell script to scrape them together yourself after the run finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I feel its better to use browsername than session id

onPrepare: function () {

```
let globals = require('protractor');

let browser = globals.browser;

browser.manage().window().maximize();
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
return browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
  var sessionId = caps.get("sessionid" + 'webdriver.remote.sessionid');
  var browsername = caps.get('browserName');
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
    // savePath: 'C:/report/report/screenshots' + sessionId
    savePath: './test/reports/screenshots' + browsername,
    screenshotsFolder: 'images',
    takeScreenshots: true,
    takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true
  }));
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, there are also two parameters that together result in unique reports. Essentially, one appends a Date&Time stamp to the report, and the other parameter specifies that previous reports are **not** to be deleted.

var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
savePath: './reports/',
**cleanDestination**: false,
**fileNameDateSuffix**: true
}));